I want pyspark to throw error, not fill column with null
Say one is reading a csv file.
It has a column, UnitPrice, that has decimal values (10.34, 20.44)
In Pyspark, code was constructed in error with
StructField("UnitPrice", IntegerType())

The data frame is loading the file when using the schema with NULL values for column UnitPrice.
df=spark.read.format("csv").schema(ordersSchema).load

I want an error to be thrown as it is not loading this column's data correctly from the CSV file.
NOTE: There may exist row with null values for UnitPrice.

Basically, you want to read the unit price as integer and need to throw error when it is other than integer data type.

also, you don't want the null values. right?

@JayashankarGS Data has null values and is of decimal type. The pyspark code was in error. But I had no indication, other than noticing return value. I would want an error thrown if cvs datatype does not match pyspark defined data type. Not just fill all values with NULL.

are you using databricks?

@JayashankarGS Fabric Apache Spark

Unfortunately, you cannot keep this kind of constraint while reading the data from file,
all you have to do is either check the condition manually or gives you the error when merging or writing to the table.
Since PySpark's schema enforcement will not inherently throw an error when type mismatches occur (it will just set the value to NULL), you need to manually check for these NULL values after loading the data and then raise an error if any are found.
Even when you set nullable to False in schema still it give you null values.
Refer this stack solution regarding that.
Manually you can check with below code.
invalid_rows = df.filter(col("UnitPrice").isNull())

# Raise an error if any NULL values are found in UnitPrice
if invalid_rows.count() > 0:
    raise ValueError("Schema validation failed: UnitPrice column contains non-integer values or nulls.")

Or
when you write data to table you will get the error automatically. Below is the sample error.
Appending data to existing table with schema of unit price as integer or double.
df.write.mode('append').saveAsTable("prices")

ERROR
[[DELTA_FAILED_TO_MERGE_FIELDS](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/error-messages/error-classes#delta_failed_to_merge_fields)] Failed to merge fields 'UnitPrice' and 'UnitPrice' SQLSTATE: 22005

But if you are open to connect databricks with you fabric notebook then delta live tables is the best option which allows you to check constraints using expectations on incoming data.
You can check more about this here.
